# Боярышник

Tags: этимология

Почему ягода называется боярышник, какое она имеет отношение к боярам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В словаре Фасмера читаем:
Боярышник Ближайшая этимология: -- растение "Crataegus", Mi. EW (17); Преобр. (1, 41) и Соболевский (РФВ 67, 217) связывают это слово с Боярин, точнее, с Боярич (откуда Барыч). Подтверждение этой точки зрения см. у Булича (ИОРЯС I, 296), который видит то же самое в диал. Баркиґ мн. ч., казанск., из *Бояръкъ. Страницы: 1,204

Ещё нашла:
Боярыня и боярышник - есть ли что общего между этими двумя словами? Словарь Ушакова значение слова «боярыня» истолковывает очень просто - жена боярина. А слово «бояре» означало в древней Киевской Руси Х-ХVII веков высшее феодальное сословие...
 Сейчас трудно установить, откуда происходит русское название «боярышник»: говорят, оно связано с легендой об одной боярыне и происходит от слова «боярыня».

Как бы ни было на самом деле, но из поколения в поколение народ передает одну старую легенду про боярышник и боярыню. Жила на Руси молодая девушка, была она помолвлена с красным молодцем. Любила молодого боярина и ждала свадьбы. Но в то время на Киевскую Русь пришло нашествие монголо-татар - войско Хана Батыя из Золотой Орды. Внук Чингис Хана облюбовал красавицу, всячески пытался войти в доверие и привлечь внимание, чтобы после - соблазнить. Но красавица отвечала отказом, храня целомудрие и верность суженому, заручившись помощью боярышника: из его цветущих веток плела и носила на голове венок. Долго оставались свидетелями событий и односельчане, и ордынское войско, пока внук Чингис Хана не выдержал и решил насильно овладеть красавицей. Он выследил девушку и начал преследование. Убегала славянка, пока хватало сил, а когда изнемогла - прижалась спиной к дереву боярышника, и пригрозила, что убьет себя, если тронет ее Хан Батый. Что сказала - то и сделала, как только двинулся к ней полководец, вынула нож и вонзила в свое сердце. Так и умерла под боярышником. С тех событий прошло много тысячелетий, имя девушки уж никто и не вспомнит, но с тех самых пор на Руси стали вылечить всех девушек, достигших возраста для замужества, боярышнями или боярынями. (http://www.lepestok.kharkov.ua/story/s20120201.htm)

Comment: P.S.В предпоследней строке, вероятно, надо читать не "вылечить", а "величать".

Comment: Красивая легенда, но сомнительно. От "боярышня" было бы "боярышенник".
Сворее все действительно от "боярич".
Да и "источник" явно не разбирается в системе титулования на Руси. Боярыня - жена боярина, борярышна - дочь. Путать никак не можно. Боярыч, разумеется, сын.